# Hours labelling for RadChart

Tags: windows-phone-7, telerik, radchart

I'm trying to use Telerik's RadChart (Spline) on WP7 to display the hourly temperature forecast.  I'm having a hard time finding information on how to set the horizontal-axis to group by hour.  The examples project contains a chart grouped by month, but when I change

`DateTimeComponent="Month" LabelFormat="MMM yyyy"`

to:

`DateTimeComponent="Hour" LabelFormat="hh ddd"`

I get a divide-by-zero error when it tries to build the axis.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[NOAA Hourly Weather Forecast Graph](http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=44.96180&lon=-93.26680&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=graphical)

Anyone know of a tutorial or what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved it for me was to switch DateTimeCategoricalAxis to a DateTimeContinuousAxis.  I found the examples in the Telerik samples app very helpful.

```
<telerikChart:DateTimeContinuousAxis
    LabelFitMode="MultiLine"
    LabelFormat="htt"
    MajorStep="6"
    LabelStyle="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"
    MajorStepUnit="Hour"
    PlotMode="OnTicks" />
```

Comment: The help documentation is a great source for help as well. http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/common-introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

For the LabelFormat can you please try "h tt"?  I don't have access to try right now, but that should work.  The format would be "3 PM"

Comment: Good catch, thanks, but unfortunately it didn't solve the larger problem.